# Azure managed identity for services on a cluster

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-managed-identity

I read about managed identity here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview

From what I understand, in order to use a user defined managed identity I need to define it, give it access rights to the resource I want to access and then set the identity in other resources so that can use that identity to get the access rights to the resource from before. All of the above are Azure defined resources.

My question is how can I use managed identity to identify services installed on a cluster? In which case the services are not Azure resources I can set the identity on so I don't know how they can use it.

Comment: what do you mean by cluster ? kubernetes ? aks ? Are you trying to assign the identity to a pod/service ?

Comment: @Thomas An AKS cluster. If I'm not mistaken a pod is the physical representation of a service and a service can contain several pods? I'm guessing that the entire service should have access

Comment: you have 2 options: [pod-identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-azure-ad-pod-identity) and [workload identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/azure-ad-workload-identity/azure-ad-workload-identity/)

Comment: @Thomas but like I said that if a service can have several pods then how will it work for all of them?

Comment: Red the documentation please. The identity will be assigned for all the pods of the same service.